# Return all objects inside nested loop in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want return all objects inside nested loop

```
const data = [{ id:1, products:[{id:1, name:'apple'}, {id:2, name:'orange'}] },
{id:2, products:[{id:3, name:'grapes'}, {id:4, name:'banana'},  {id:5, name:'dragonFruit'}] 
}]
 let result = data.map(item=>{
 item?.products?.map(row=> return row) })
console.log(result )
```

result should be:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'apple'}
{id: 2, name: 'orange'}
{id: 3, name: 'grapes'}
{id: 4, name: 'banana'}
{id: 5, name: 'dragonFruit'}
]
```

Comment: For this particular case you can use `let result = data.flatMap (item => item.products);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use `flatMap` with `map`.

```
let result = data.flatMap(({products})=> 
    products.map(prd=> ({...prd })))
```

Let me show an example:

```js
const data = [
    { id:1, 
        products:[
            {id:1, name:'apple'}, 
            {id:2, name:'orange'}
        ] 
    },
    {id:2, 
        products:[
            {id:3, name:'grapes'}, 
            {id:4, name:'banana'},  
            {id:5, name:'dragonFruit'}
        ] 
    }
]
 
let result = data.flatMap(({products})=> 
    products.map(prd=> ({ ...prd })))
 console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [{ id:1, products:[{id:1, name:'apple'}, {id:2, name:'orange'}] },
{id:2, products:[{id:3, name:'grapes'}, {id:4, name:'banana'},  {id:5, name:'dragonFruit'}] 
}]
let result = data.map(item=>{
    let res = item.products.map((val) =>{
    return val
  })
  return res
})

console.log(result)
```

check the above snippet, here inner map function return the value to the outer map and from the outer map function I'm returning the result

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `flatMap`. Read more about it at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const data = [
    { 
        id:1, 
        products:[{id:1, name:'apple'}, {id:2, name:'orange'}] 
    },
    {
       id:2, 
       products:[{id:3, name:'grapes'}, {id:4, name:'banana'},  {id:5, name:'dragonFruit'}] 
    }
];
const flatResult = data.flatMap(({products})=> products);
console.log(flatResult)
```

The above will return the output as

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "apple"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "orange"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "grapes"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "banana"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "dragonFruit"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a nested loop, first `map` over the `data` and then over the `products`.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    products: [
      { id: 1, name: "apple" },
      { id: 2, name: "orange" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    products: [
      { id: 3, name: "grapes" },
      { id: 4, name: "banana" },
      { id: 5, name: "dragonFruit" },
    ],
  },
];

function App() {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(({ products }) =>
        products.map((p) => <li key={p.id}>{p.name}</li>)
      )}
    </ul>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```